# Connection string not correct on EF 6 Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure, entity-framework-6, azure-functions

I have a very simple Azure function which updates rows on a database.
This works fine locally via Postman.

This is the very simple call I have in my Azure function

```
   string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CatsDBEntities"].ConnectionString;
            using (var context = new CatsDBEntities(connectionString))
            {
                //   using (var db = new CatsDBEntities())
                {
                    Cat cat = new Cat
                    {
                        Name = "BengA",
                        Id = id
                    };

                    context.Cats.Add(cat);
                    context.SaveChanges();

                }


                response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            }
        }

        catch (System.Exception)
```

And here is my context

```
  public CatsDBEntities(string connectionString) : base(connectionString) { }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }
    
        public virtual DbSet<Cat> Cats { get; set; }
```

Here is my connection string in local settings (I know this doesn't matter when deploying to Azure but I am using this as an example of my connection string):

```
metadata=res://*/CatModel.csdl|res://*/CatModel.ssdl|res://*/CatModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='data source=x.database.windows.net;initial catalog=CatsDB;user id=x;password=!;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework'",
```

and within Azure, I am entering my connection string like this:

[image]

This works great locally through Postman get a 200 but when deployed to Azure I get a 500 and this is my latest error:

[image]

This is error means nothing anyway because I have tried several times now and I keep changing the string and the error sometimes changes and sometimes not.

I have added the EF6 database first project as a separate project to my Azure function and I have put a reference between the two projects.

Comment: Try putting value of connectionstring in double quotes in azure

Comment: that just gives an error on the first character ".

Comment: any ideas anyone please ?

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in the post that EF6 DataBase is added first then,
This is caused by how EF model first connection strings are generated.

The EF connection string builder requires a plain connection string in the constructor.

You can Refer this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55745685/connection-string-for-entity-framework-in-an-azure-function) thread link for more information.